# Firefox Cannot Copy/Paste srcset image in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When I copy/paste Image(with `src` attribute) from other web page is working good. But, when I copy/paste Image(with `srcset` attribute) from other web page is not working in firefox. But in chrome and IE, it is working good.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: do you know any answer for this pb??

Comment: Is there a question?